# How do I switch OS user in Datagrip to Postgres via SSH?

Tags: datagrip

When I connect to my database remotely I use `ssh` to connect to the remote machine, then I run `sudo -u postgres psql` to access PostgresSQL. The `postgres` user is passwordless in my OS.

I can make an SSH tunnel connect in Datagrip, but I can't seem to find a way to switch to `postgres` user prior to attempting to access the database.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to configure SSH tunnel on datasource ssh/ssl tab (host/port/username/password).
Secondly, you need to specify database credentials to your db on general tab.
Also, make sure you configured server correctly for non-local connections.

You should go to ~/.ssh/config file and set the tunnel with the user, which is used on the server, and put 'postgres' as a user name in the connection properties.

Note, it is working only in 2017.3 EAP now (release will be available this week)

[image]